# Getting associated text with Ctrl+V using C#

Tags: .net, winforms

I am using a rich text box to enter some variables.
I am restricting the user from entering some special characters.
But user is able to enter the same values by copying from a notepad and pasting it in text box.
How can I restrict the user from doing so?

Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: How do the currect restrictions work? can you post an example of you code?

Comment: As per the requirement user should not enter either '{' or '}'.

Comment: handling the same in KeyPress event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi to prevent pasting from clipboard in the `KeyDown` event handler you can check if `Ctrl` was pressed and if so you set `e.handled` to true. this should work :)

Comment: I have to restrict pasting if text contains '{' or '}'.

Comment: then you can set the handled to True only if the Clipboard.GetText returns text containing those chars you want to avoid pasting...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own filter method/class. So check sometimes (either timer, event, whatever) for bad charackters and garbage them!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good SO question that i think addresses this:

[Intercept paste event on HtmlEditor WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611350/intercept-paste-event-on-htmleditor-winforms)

You have to sub-class it and stop the paste message from getting farther down, by overriding WndPrc.  Then, call your own function to handle the paste.

I think there is an easier way to locate the paste message, though.  Ignore his code for inserting the content, since that doesn't apply to an RTF.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event, in the handler you can unhook the handler, modify the text, and rehook the handler (to avoid it calling itself infinetly)

That should also work for users right clicking and selecting paste from the context menu, im not sure that would trigger the `KeyDown` event.

Comment: here for me copying & pasting using mouse disabled. And using text changed event will not work for me